# Tower is sometimes merges two branches when I change the head, is this being seen by anyone else? What is the cause?

Tags: macos, git-tower

Twice in the last month I've experienced an issue where the branch I was previously on is being merged into the branch I am now on when I reassign the head branch. I'm 100% certain that in neither case did I explicitly choose to merge the branches. Is this a Tower bug? Am I alone in experiencing this?

Comment: Haven't seen this so I'm inclined to believe it's something you're doing, albeit unintentionally.

Comment: I agree with you but I can't figure out what I did. I spoke with the Tower support and they ensured to me that the only ways to merge are to right click or to drag and drop. But both ways have a prompt to double check that's what you're trying to do and I obviously would have stopped at that point. So I'm truly confused.